# how to find the SSH port data?

Tags: ssh

I have not used my RPi for a while and forgot the SSH parameters.
I am positive the SSH is enabled, it used to work and I have not changed anything.
Is there a way to "scan" for RPi SSH from my PC ?
Or do I have to physically connect to RPi to find out ?

Comment: Which OS is your PC running? @Arkadiusz Drabczyk has mentioned a solution for (I think) GNU/Linux but we do not know that that is what you are using. BTW If you have not read through the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) yet it could give you something extra to *wave around* your Avatar until the end of this years *WinterBash* as well as helping to introduce you to this corner of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This is not actually a Pi question as you need a PC program.  A search for port scanner will show 100s - please choose one from a reputable company. Make sure it runs LAN side and does not check you router ports!

Answer (score 1):

You can use nmap to check open ports on your RPi:

```
$ nmap raspberrypi
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-24 17:24 CET
Nmap scan report for raspberrypi (192.168.1.169)
Host is up (0.0092s latency).
Other addresses for raspberrypi (not scanned): fdd4:6b0c:9a70::616
rDNS record for 192.168.1.169: raspberrypi.lan
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.20 seconds
```

Use IP address instead of `raspberrypi` hostname if there is no DNS
server in your network. Notice that nmap will show the name of the
protocol which it believes is working on the given port so if you set
SSH to use another port, say 2222 you will get:

```
$ nmap raspberrypi
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-12-24 17:26 CET
Nmap scan report for raspberrypi (192.168.1.169)
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Other addresses for raspberrypi (not scanned): fdd4:6b0c:9a70::616
rDNS record for 192.168.1.169: raspberrypi.lan
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2222/tcp open  EtherNetIP-1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.65 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what operating system you are using on the PC. But just use your SSH client and connect to the RasPi using username **pi** and destination name **raspberrypi**. On a Unix like system it would look

```
pc ~$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
```